# My module form never submits

Tags: nodes, forms, 8

I'm developing my first module in Drupal 8 to programmatically create nodes of a custom content type. The submission handler I add is never called.

This is the button to which the form submission handler is attached.

```
$form['addAds'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Save Your Ads'),
  '#attributes' => ['id' => 'addAdsBtn', 'class' => ['hiddenselect']],
  '#submit' => array('ajax_example_formSubmit'),
);
```

This is the submission handler.

```
function ajax_example_formSubmit($form, &$form_state) {
  $new_node = array();
  foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
    $new_node[$key] = $value;
  }


  $entity_type = "node";
  $bundle = $form_state->getValue('level1');


  $entity_def = \Drupal::entityManager()->getDefinition($entity_type);


  $new_node[$entity_def->get('entity_keys')['bundle']] = $bundle;

  $new_post = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->create($new_node);
  $new_post->save();
}
```

What is wrong in the code?
this is my complete Form Code:

```
class Place_AdsForm extends FormBase {

public $classifiedForms;

public function getFormId() {
    return 'ajax_example_form';
}

public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $this->types = Place_AdsController::getClassifiedContentTypes();

    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'Place_Ads/general';
    $form['depth'] = [
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => '',
    ];
    $form['ajax_wrapper'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'ajax-wrapper', 'class' => ['shownselect']],
    ];

    $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper1'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'ajax-wrapper1', 'class' => ['shownselect', 'classified_cat']],
    ];
    $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper2'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'ajax-wrapper2', 'class' => ['shownselect', 'classified_cat']],
    ];
    $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper3'] = array(
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'ajax-wrapper3', 'class' => ['hiddenselect', 'classified_cat']],
    );
    $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper4'] = array(
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'ajax-wrapper4', 'class' => ['hiddenselect', 'classified_cat']],
    );
    $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper1']['level1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#description' => 'Please select level one term',
        '#options' => $this->types,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'class' => array(
                'mycategory'
            ),
        ),
        '#ajax' => array(

            'callback' => '::level1SelectedCallback',

            'wrapper' => 'ajax-wrapper2',
            'effect' => 'fade',

            'event' => 'change',
            'progress' => array(

                'type' => 'throbber',

                'message' => NULL,
            ),
        ),
    );

    $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper3']['level3'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#description' => 'Please select level three term',
        //'#options' => '',
        '#ajax' => array(
            // Function to call when event on form element triggered.
            'callback' => '::level3SelectedCallback',
            // Effect when replacing content. Options: 'none' (default), 'slide', 'fade'.
            'wrapper' => 'ajax_wrapper4',
            'effect' => 'fade',
            // Javascript event to trigger Ajax. Currently for: 'onchange'.
            'event' => 'change',
            'progress' => array(
                // Graphic shown to indicate ajax. Options: 'throbber' (default), 'bar'.
                'type' => 'throbber',
                // Message to show along progress graphic. Default: 'Please wait...'.
                'message' => NULL,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper4']['level4'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#description' => 'Please select level four term',
        //'#options' => '',
        '#ajax' => array(
            // Function to call when event on form element triggered.
            'callback' => '::level4SelectedCallback',
            // Effect when replacing content. Options: 'none' (default), 'slide', 'fade'.
            'wrapper' => 'fields_wrapper',
            'effect' => 'fade',
            // Javascript event to trigger Ajax. Currently for: 'onchange'.
            'event' => 'change',
            'progress' => array(
                // Graphic shown to indicate ajax. Options: 'throbber' (default), 'bar'.
                'type' => 'throbber',
                // Message to show along progress graphic. Default: 'Please wait...'.
                'message' => NULL,
            ),
        ),
    );
    foreach ($this->types as $key => $value) {
        if ($key !== 0) {
            $form[$key . '_fields_wrapper'] = [
                '#type' => 'container',
                '#attributes' => ['id' => $key . '-fields-wrapper', 'class' => ['hiddenselect']],
            ];
        }
    }
    foreach ($this->types as $key => $value) {
        if ($key !== 0) {
            $currFields = Place_AdsController::contentTypeFieldsAsFields($key);
            $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create(['type' => $key]);
            $myform = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($node);
            $this->classifiedForms[$key] = $myform;

            foreach ($currFields as $field) {
                //$name = $field->id();
                $n = $field->getName();
                $form[$key . '_fields_wrapper'][$n] = $myform[$n];
            }
        }
    }

    if ($form_state->getValue('level1') != false) {
        //$form['#action'] = $this->classifiedForms[$form_state->getValue('level1')]['#action'];
        $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper2']['level2'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#description' => 'Please select level two term',
            '#attributes' => array(
                'class' => array(
                    'mycategory'
                ),
            ),
            '#ajax' => array(
                // Function to call when event on form element triggered.
                'callback' => '::level2SelectedCallback',
                // Effect when replacing content. Options: 'none' (default), 'slide', 'fade'.
                'wrapper' => 'ajax-wrapper3',
                'effect' => 'fade',
                // Javascript event to trigger Ajax. Currently for: 'onchange'.
                'event' => 'change',
                'progress' => array(
                    // Graphic shown to indicate ajax. Options: 'throbber' (default), 'bar'.
                    'type' => 'throbber',
                    // Message to show along progress graphic. Default: 'Please wait...'.
                    'message' => NULL,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    $form['addAds'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Save Your Ads'),
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'addAdsBtn', 'class' => ['hiddenselect']],
        '#submit' => ['::ajax_example_formSubmit'],

    );
    /* $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
      $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Add'),
      '#submit' => array("::submitForm"),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
      '#attributes' => ['id' => 'addAdsBtn', 'class' => ['hiddenselect']],
      ); */
    return $form;
}

function ajax_example_formSubmit($form, &$form_state) {
    $new_node = array();
    foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
        $new_node[$key] = $value;
    }

    //define entity type and bundle
    $entity_type = "node";
    $bundle = $form_state->getValue('level1');


    $entity_def = \Drupal::entityManager()->getDefinition($entity_type);

    $new_node[$entity_def->get('entity_keys')['bundle']] = $bundle;

    $new_post = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->create($new_node);
    $new_post->save();
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Display result.
}

public function level1SelectedCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Instantiate an AjaxResponse Object to return.
    $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
    $val = $form_state->getValue('level1');
    $terms = Place_AdsController::getsubCategory($val);
    /*
      foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
      $n = $field->getName();
      $ajax_response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#fields-wrapper', $form['fields_wrapper'][$n]));
      }
     */
    $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper2']['level2']['#options'] = $terms;

    $ajax_response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#ajax-wrapper2', $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper2']['level2']));
    // We can still invoke the change command on #edit-user-name so it triggers Ajax on that element to validate username.
    $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#ajax-wrapper2', 'change'));
    $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#ajax-wrapper3', 'change'));
    $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#level2', 'change'));
    $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'changeClass', ['#ajax-wrapper3', 'shownselect', 'hiddenselect']));
    $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'changeClass', ['#ajax-wrapper4', 'shownselect', 'hiddenselect']));
    foreach ($this->types as $key => $value) {
        if ($key !== 0)
            $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'hideFields', [$key]));
    }

    $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'changeClass', ['#addAdsBtn', 'shownselect', 'hiddenselect']));

    $form_state->setRebuild(True);

    return $ajax_response;
}

public function level2SelectedCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    // Instantiate an AjaxResponse Object to return.
    $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
    $terms = array();
    if ($form_state->getValue('level2') != false) {
        $val = $form_state->getValue('level2');
        $terms = Place_AdsController::getTerms($val);
    }

    if (count($terms) > 0) {
        $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper3']['level3']['#options'] = $terms;


        $ajax_response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#ajax-wrapper3', $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper3']['level3']));

        // We can still invoke the change command on #edit-user-name so it triggers Ajax on that element to validate username.
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#ajax-wrapper3', 'change'));
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#level3', 'change'));
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#edit-level3', 'change'));
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'changeClass', ['#ajax-wrapper3', 'hiddenselect', 'shownselect']));
    } else {
        $arg = [$form_state->getValue('level1')];
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'showFields', $arg));
        foreach ($this->types as $key => $value) {
            if ($key !== 0 && $key !== $form_state->getValue('level1'))
                $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'hideFields', [$key]));
        }
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'changeClass', ['#addAdsBtn', 'hiddenselect', 'shownselect']));
    }
    $form_state->setRebuild(True);
    return $ajax_response;
}

public function level3SelectedCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
    $terms = array();
    if ($form_state->getValue('level3') != false) {
        $val = $form_state->getValue('level3');
        $terms = Place_AdsController::getTerms($val);
    }

    if (count($terms) > 0) {
        $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper4']['level4']['#options'] = $terms;


        $ajax_response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#ajax-wrapper4', $form['ajax_wrapper']['ajax_wrapper4']['level4']));

        // We can still invoke the change command on #edit-user-name so it triggers Ajax on that element to validate username.
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#ajax-wrapper4', 'change'));
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#level4', 'change'));
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#edit-level4', 'change'));
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'changeClass', ['#ajax-wrapper4', 'hiddenselect', 'shownselect']));
    } else {
        $arg = [$form_state->getValue('level1')];
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'showFields', $arg));
        foreach ($this->types as $key => $value) {
            if ($key !== 0 && $key !== $form_state->getValue('level1'))
                $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'hideFields', [$key]));
        }
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'changeClass', ['#addAdsBtn', 'hiddenselect', 'shownselect']));
    }
    $form_state->setRebuild(True);

    return $ajax_response;
}

public function level4SelectedCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
    $arg = [$form_state->getValue('level1')];
    $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'showFields', $arg));
    foreach ($this->types as $key => $value) {
        if ($key !== 0 && $key !== $form_state->getValue('level1'))
            $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'hideFields', [$key]));
    }
    $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'changeClass', ['#addAdsBtn', 'hiddenselect', 'shownselect']));


    $form_state->setRebuild(True);

    return $ajax_response;
}
```

}

Comment: are you trying to make your submit ajax driven? or just a normal submit?

Comment: sorry but I don't get what driven means? I guess its normal submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out...
my proplem was so silly that every select must have '#options' set to null in Formbuild function even if it's hidden and not yet filled..

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, attaching custom submit handler is a bit different in Drupal 8.
change `'#submit' => array('ajax_example_formSubmit')` to `'#submit' => ['::ajax_example_formSubmit'],`

```
$form['addAds'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Save Your Ads'),
  '#attributes' => ['id' => 'addAdsBtn', 'class' => ['hiddenselect']],
  '#submit' => array('ajax_example_formSubmit'),
);
```

to

```
$form['addAds'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Save Your Ads'),
  '#attributes' => ['id' => 'addAdsBtn', 'class' => ['hiddenselect']],
  '#submit' => ['::ajax_example_formSubmit'],
);
```

Here is another working example

```
namespace Drupal\example\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class ExampleForm extends Formbase {

    public function getFormId() {
      return 'example_form';
    }

    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

      $form['title'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Title'),
      );

      $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        '#submit' => ['::custom_submit_handler'], // Comment this to use submitForm instead of custom submit handler
      );
      return $form;
    }

    public function custom_submit_handler(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      drupal_set_message('Hello World 1');
    }

    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      drupal_set_message('Hello World 2');
    }
}
```

Comment: I try it but its not working, after debugging the code, it's not entering the breakpoint in the submit handler ajax_example_formSubmit !!!

Comment: can you update your snippet and post the complete code? not just the form submit

Comment: ok I'll do it as quick as I can

Comment: how about moving contents of `ajax_example_formSubmit` inside submitForm?

Comment: I try it but also faild to submit

Comment: did you try to check dblog? might be error message to start with?

Comment: yes there is a notice:
Notice: Undefined index: #value in template_preprocess_textarea() (line 381 of C:\wamp64\www\emad\demo01\core\includes\form.inc).